# Android Studio не видит телефон по usb

Tags: android, android-studio

Xiaomi Redmi Note 7 Pro, отладка по usb включена, в Troubleshoot устройство отображается, но когда запускаю, в окне "Select Deployment Target" устройства нет. В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Какая ОС на компьютере?

Comment: Style-7, Windows 8.1

Comment: Если USB debugging включен, то похоже на "кривой" драйвер. Попробуйте через командную строку посмотреть "adb devices" сначала, затем установите другой драйвер

Answer (score 1):

сначала тут запрети доступ:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом передерни шнурок, должно выйти это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1):

Сначала вставьте сим-карту (обязательно), затем зарегистрируйте Mi-аккаунт, потом зайдите в режим разработчика и активируйте `Отладка по USB` и `Установка через USB`.

P.S. Пока не вставите сим-карту и не зарегистрируете ми-аккаунт пункт `Установка через USB` не сможете активировать, следовательно и устанавливать приложения для тестирования.

Comment: Сим-карта стоит, аккаунт зарегистрировал через Mi Community, отладка и установка по usb стоит. Проблема осталась.

Comment: Перед установкой на самом устройстве всплывает окно, в котором вы должны разрешить установку, разрешаете?

Comment: Вообще ничего на самом устройстве не всплывает. Ну только, когда подключаю телефон, уведомление что оладка по usb разрешена, естественно.